# numpy.load unable to interpret pickle file as pickle in anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two python scripts where one needs to be run using the older version of python (2.7) and other in the newer version i.e. 3.6. So I created two environments in Anaconda- one with python 2.7.8 (old) and the other with Python 3.6 (new). I am using a data files say “test_input.csv” and “test_input.sig”.

I am able to run the first script file in the python 2.7.8 environment which basically preprocess the data i.e. unwrapping categorical variables, normalizing the variables, etc and dumps it into a pickle. So, it generated the “**test_input.csv_normalized.pickle**” file. But now when I am trying to run the second script in python 3.6 in Anaconda where I am trying to load this pickle file i.e.

> import numpy as np
>
> y=np.load('test_input.csv_normalized.pickle')

But here I am getting the following error:-

> File "/..../python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 413, in
> load return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position
> 0: ordinal not in range(128) During handling of the above exception,
> another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "ClusterId.py", line 84, in 
> y=np.load('test_input.csv_normalized.pickle')   File
> "/home/putatund/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
> line 416, in load "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" %
> repr(file))
>
> OSError: Failed to interpret file
> 'test_input.csv_normalized.pickle' as a pickle

Any idea what might be the issue? And how to resolve this.

Comment: What method did you use to save the file?  `np.save`?  Also, what is the data format before being saved?

Comment: I have just use a .dump('test_input.csv_normalized.pickle') in the previous script to get the pickle file. I haven't used np.save.

Comment: @ChrisMueller It was a csv file before being saved.

Comment: pickle between Py2 and Py3 is iffy.  `np.save/load` uses pickle for non-array objects.  If the file was created with pickle, rather than `np.save` it would better to load it with pickle - and play with compatibility options if needed.  Tell us about the Py2 data and show how the file was created.